# Application of Trotter-Kato theorem in PDE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, applications, semigroup-of-operators

Can anybody please help me to understand when do we apply the Trotter-Kato theorem while dealing with PDE's? When is this theorem useful?
I might need very simple explanation, since I am not "Professional mathematician".

Thank you.

Comment: You can find quite some literature by a web search. For instance: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/220576661_The_Trotter-Kato_theorem_and_approximation_of_PDEs